# Custom validation rule is not working properly (the rule passes but should not)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the form below for the user to select the quantities of each registration type that he wants.

For example if the conference has two registration types (ex: general and plus) the user can select that he wants quantity "1" of the registration type "general" and quantity "1" for the registration type "plus". If the user does this selection  he goes to the registration page, it works fine.

But if the user dont select any quantity for none registration type instead of appear a validation error it shows "Undefined variable: selectedRtypes
".

Do you know where is the error in the RegistrationTypeQuantity custom rule?

Method to store the selected quantities by the user for each registration type

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{

    $request->validate([
        'rtypes' => ['required', 'array', new RegistrationTypeQuantity],
    ]);

    $rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');

    $total = 0;
    foreach ($rtypeQuantities as $rtypeName => $quantity) {
        if ($quantity) {

            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name', $rtypeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $rtype->price;

            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            $total += $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['subtotal'];
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['total'] = $total;

            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions'] = $rtype->questions;
            $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['id'] = $rtype->id;
            //dd($selectedRtypes);
        }
    }

    Session::put('selectedRtypes', $selectedRtypes);
    Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);
    Session::put('total', $total);

    return redirect(route('conferences.registration', 
    ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
}
```

The RegistrationTypeQuantity rule:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {

        foreach($value as $key=>$v) {

            // if $v is null 
            if ( is_null($v)) return false;

            $rtype = RegistrationType::where('name',$key)->first();
            // if there is no $rtype 
            if ( ! $rtype) return false;

            if($v == 0)
                return true;

            // $rtype was found
            if ( ($v < $rtype->min_participants || $v > $rtype->max_participants) )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If the user dont select any quantity

```
$rtypeQuantities = $request->get('rtypes');
dd($rtypeQuantities);
```

shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "general" => "0"
  "plus" => "0"
]
```

In the select menu for the user select the quantities for each registration type the user should only be allowed to select a value between the min_participants and max_participants.

The min_participants is a column of the registration_types table and means that is the minimum quantity that the user can select for the registration.

The max_participants is a column of the registration_types table and means that is the maximum quantity that the user can select for a registration type.

So, for example if the min_participants is "0" and max_participants is "2" for the registration type "general" the user can only select a quantity between 0 and 2 for the registration type "general".

```
 <select class="custom-select form-control rtype_name" id="rtype_{{ $rtype->id }}" 
                        data-price="{{ $rtype->price }}"
                        name="rtypes[{{ $rtype->name }}]">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    @for ($i = $rtype->min_participants; $i <= $rtype-> max_participants; $i++)
                        <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
                    @endfor
                </select>
```

So the custom rule should validate if the user fills the select menu field, because it is required and also that the value introduced by the user is between the min_participants and max_participants.

Answer (score 0):

You define `$selectedRtypes` inside of a foreach loop only if `$quantity` is truthy.  Therefore, `$selectedRtypes` would be undefined any time you do not have a valid `$quantity`.

Either define `$selectedRtypes` outside of the loop since you rely on it being defined, or validate your input array to make sure there is a valid quantity provided.

The latter seems necessary since you also rely on an `$rtype` which is also defined inside the loop and relies on a valid quantity and type.  A quantity of 0 seems to pass your validation, but would fail your `if ($quantity)` check.

Comment: Thanks, but the validation error still not appears. Instead of appear the validation error saying that the user needs to select the quantities it appears "Undefined variable: selectedRtype " in : " <span class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo e(number_format($selectedRtype['total'], 2)); ?>$</span>".

Comment: You have multiple problems if you're trying to use this as a view variable.  You're adding these to the session, not passing them as variables to the view.

Comment: The storeQuantities() has the "        return redirect(route('conferences.registration', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
" that redirects the user to the registration page because it calls the method displayRegistrationPage():

Comment: "public function displayRegistrationPage(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{$conference = Conference::find($id);$selectedRtypes = Session::get('selectedRtypes'); $customQuestions = Session::get('customQuestions');$total = Session::get('total');$countries = Facades\Countries::all();if (isset($selectedRtypes)){return view('conferences.registration',['selectedRtypes' =>$selectedRtypes, 'total' => $total, 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug, 'countries' => $countries, 'conference' => $conference]);}else{return redirect(route('conferences.show', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])); }}"

Comment: It seems this is becoming too broad for a single answer.  I recommend you do some more learning regarding how to debug and possibly visit a discussion forum instead of SO.  SO is Q&A, not a good format for someone who needs to discuss through a large problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add before foreach

```
$selectedRtypes = [];
```

and you have probably error in `Session::put('customQuestions', $selectedRtypes[$rtype->name]['questions']);`. There will be always last result from loop as a key.

Comment: Thanks, but the validation error still not appears. Instead of appear the validation error saying that the user needs to select the quantities it appears "Undefined variable: selectedRtype " in : " <span class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo e(number_format($selectedRtype['total'], 2)); ?>$</span>".